# Building repeating strings with spaces between the repeats

Tags: scheme, racket

`repeat` takes in a number and a string, and returns the string repeated `n` times, separated by a space.

```
;; repeat: number string -> string
(define (repeat n str)
  (replicate n str))

(repeat 2 "home")
```

gives me:

```
"homehome"
```

How would I add a space so it can give me "home home"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a space to the string `str` at the end, before passing it to `replicate`:

```
(replicate n (string-append str " "))
```

That'll leave an extra space at the end, if you want to get rid of it do as @Tobia suggests:

```
(string-trim (replicate n (string-append str " ")))
```

Comment: 'string-append: expects a string as 1st argument, given 3' is what i am getting.

Comment: Or just trim the space away: `(string-trim (replicate (string-append b " ") n))`

Comment: @Josh It seems the parameters are inverted (I thought `n` was the number of repetitions). I updated my answer, please try again.

Comment: @Tobia: apologies, but I edited the question's arguments because the names of the original parameters were so confusing.  So I've renamed `b` to `n`, and `n` to `str`.

Answer (score 1):

Racket has a build-in function *string-join* for this, so in plain Racket this would be

```
> (string-join (build-list 2 (lambda (i) "home")))
"home home"
```

Comment: Yes, but the other answer is more efficient, as it does not build an intermediate list.

Comment: That's wrong. If you look up the definition of replicate, it uses build-list as well (see collects/lang/private/todo.rkt).